# Некоторые плагины для jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ищу плагины (они вроде так называются) jQuery для реализации:

1. Модальных окон, желательно без графики, только css. Также желательно, чтобы подгружались на json.
2. Асинхронной отправки post запроса с получением ответа от скрипта.

Поискал на сайте jQuery, ничего конкретного не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) $.modal();
2) $.post(action-script, {data}, function(msg){
     alert(msg); //выполняется при успешном ответе от action-script
   });
```

синтаксис {data} - {id: 2, name: "Xan", do: some_variavle}.

$.post(); - производная от функции $.ajax();

$.ajax не модуль, а метод JQ. $.modal(); - UI.